# Storing HashMap inside Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, hashmap

Given the following situation:

```
Map<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap();
Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap();

map2.put("Grp A", "a");
map2.put("Grp B", "b");

map1.put("Grp",map2);
```

How can get the "Grp A" value from map1 ?

Comment: [`Map#get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-)?

Comment: *FYI:* You're using *raw* generics. Don't do that! Use the diamond operator: `new HashMap<>()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply retrieve map2 from map1 by casting to a Map and then get the desired value from that Map:

```
return ((Map<String,String>)map1.get("Grp")).get("Grp A");
```

However, better practice would be to check that map2 isn't null before retrieving "Grp A":

```
Map<String,String> map = (Map<String,String>)map1.get("Grp");
if (map != null) {
    return map.get("Grp A");
}
```

@Eran's answer would be better practice, but OP asked how to retrieve the value from the given HashMap.

Answer (score 6):

Change `map1` to:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
```

Then `map1.get("Grp").get("Grp A")` will work.

Of course, in general it would be safer to store `map1.get("Grp")` in a variable, and check if it's not null before calling the second `get()`:

```
String value = null;
Map<String, String> inner = map1.get("Grp");
if (inner != null) {
    value = inner.get("Grp A");
}
```

If you must keep `map1` as `Map<String, Object>` (for example, if you must store values of different types in it), you'll have to check the type of the value you got from the outer `Map`, and cast it to a `Map` before obtaining the inner value:

```
String value = null;
Object innerObj = map1.get("Grp");
if (innerObj instanceof Map<?,?>) {
    Map<?,?> inner = (Map<?,?>) map1.get("Grp");
    Object obj = inner.get("Grp A");
    if (obj instanceof String) {
        value = (String) obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you defined map1 as `Map<String, Object>` it's values are returned as objects.
You can solve this by either by .
**Casting** .

```
Map<String,String> map2 =  = (Map<String,String>)map1.get("Gep")
```

**Using the right generics for m1** .

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution for the above problem

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HashMapExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();

        map2.put("Grp A", "a");
        map2.put("Grp B", "b");

        map1.put("Grp",map2);

        System.out.println(map1.get("Grp").get("Grp A"));
    }
}
```

Hope this will work
Thanks...